# Calculate a time used with start and end times on different days

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to calculate the amount of time an asset is being used for a given day.  So for example if an asset is used from 1/1/2015 4:00 AM to 1/1/2015 2:00PM I can use a datediff function for the 2 times and get a difference of 10 hours meaning the the asset was used for 10 hours on the 1st.  The problem occurs when the end time goes past midnight.  In that situation I would need to know how many hours the asset was used till midnight. Is there an easy way to calculate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
Dim HoursUsed As Integer

If DateDiff("d", StartTime, StopTime) > 0 Then
    StopTime = DateValue(StopTime)
End If
HoursUsed = DateDiff("h", StartTime, StopTime)
```

For an exact measure of time use:

```
Dim TimeUsed As Date

TimeUsed = StopTime - StartTime
```

Then format TimeUsed as you like.